# ul li with different list icon on hover

Tags: html, css

This is what I am having difficulty making in html/css.

[image: List with different icons and background]

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">General overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">E-mail and FTP features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Datacenter and capacity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CMS and scripts</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#features li {
    width: 216px; height: 39px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0; margin: 0;
}

#features li a {
    background: url(http://www.pwnhost.com/images/listicon.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4d71b2;
}

#features li a:hover {
    background: url(http://www.pwnhost.com/images/listselected.png) no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
```

5 icons normally, 5 different icons on hover with background. I want to do this only using the icon images. What is the best way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: You're going to need a class on each `<li>`.  Then you'd do well to use a sprite and change the `background-position` for each class.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having? Does your code not work? Can you provide a jsFiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: you could simply <li><img src="><span>text text text</span></li>

Comment: My problem is positioning the icon properly and using border-bottom for the dashed line. I can make this really ugly but I want to know the best way to do this.

Comment: @Travesty3 Because if each list item has a different background image, it'll need a different selector

Comment: @davidpauljunior: Yeah, I deleted the comment once I realized why you were suggesting that. For the sake of argument, however, he doesn't technically *need* a class on each `<li>`. A separate id on each one would also work.

Comment: Is there a way I can use the same background and still change the icon?

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes an ID would also work.  Perhaps '_need_' was too strong.  But he may have this in multiple places on the page, so I erred on the side of caution.

Comment: @AndB are you talking about the gradient (in your last comment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like Entypo icons, which would make it even easier to do.  I use Font Awesome, but it's the same concept.

http://fontawesome.io/icons/

http://www.entypo.com/characters/

Essentially, on hover, when the text changes

Heres a fiddle for you with code!

http://jsfiddle.net/WyN7w/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Book Mark</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Lets Fly</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-gears"></i> Settings</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Error Messages</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css");

ul {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #1c6e86;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #113945;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
    background: #113945;
    color: #fff;
}

li .fa {
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: On top of that, you can use these 'Typography Icons' anywhere on your website, so instead of having 50 icon images, you can load the Stylesheet once, and add <i class=""></i> whenever you need an icon

Comment: This is will help me so much. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, always happy to help.  I hope it all works out for you, don't hesitate to reply to this if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an nth-child selector in your css targeting each of your li elements to add the icon rather than applying the icon to your anchor tags.

Using the same HTML structure, the CSS would look something like:

```
ul li:first-child {
background:url(images/icon.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 50px; /*width of icon*/
}
ul li:first-child:hover {
background:url(images/icon-hover.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 50px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
background:url(images/second-icon.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 50px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
background:url(images/second-icon-hover.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 50px;
}
/*Repeat for all other child elements */
```